# Linq Split properties of Class and assign it to another Custom Class

Tags: linq

I have a Complex Situation now and i am terribly stuck. Kindly Let me know if you can share some light to it.

I have a

List Which will have the Following properties

```
public class Categories 
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ValueCode { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }           
    }
```

This will have Values like

```
Category1/SubCategory1
cat1/sc1
5

Category1/SubCategory2
cat1/sc2
4

Category 2/Subcategory1
cat2/sc1
5

Category 2/Subcategory2
cat2/sc2
23
```

I created a Custom Class to fill in the values

```
public class JobCateogry 
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ValueCode { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }
        public List<JobCateogry> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to Split the String in the Code Value and assign it to the SubCategory.

Like My Final out of jobCategory would be

- Category1
- Cat1
- 9

  - SubCategory1
  - sub1
  - 5
  - SubCateogry2
  - sub2
  - 4

I tried to Split the string and assign it to the new class in two step first by splitting and then by assiging. But i am sure i am doing it the wrong way, because the moment i split, i loose the count .

```
var lstCategory =  Categories 
                        .Where(i => i.count > 0)
                        .Select(item => item.valueCode.Split('/')                                        
                        .Select(k =>(k)).ToList();

List<JobCategories> jobcategories = lstCategory
    .Select(item => item.Split(QueryStringConstants.CAT_SEPERATOR.ToCharArray()[0]))
    .GroupBy(tokens => tokens[0].Trim(), tokens => tokens[1])
    .Select(g => new JobCategories(g.Key,  g.DisplayName,g.ToList(),)).ToList();
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: I am getting the Categories and subcategories Split. But i am only getting their Value codes. I am not getting their Displayname and Count

Comment: Show us the string that is split.

Comment: Voted to close due to unclear question. However it SOUNDS like you are trying to construct a `Tree` using a `TreePath` value. You also seem to want to use Linq as your new favorite hammer. Please confirm.

Comment: You can tell me what is Unclear and i can Explain it to you rather than closing. As far as i see, i have mentioned what is required and what i have tried and what difficulty i am facing.  And No. Not Exactly. I am not really hell bent on using LinQ. Even a Simple For Loop would do. The Reason i mentioned Linq was because i thought it would be easier for this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

A bit weird task

It might not be the best solution and it only works with the two layers :-), and i tried keeping a lot of linq for the fun of it

anyway hope it can get you moving forward.

full code snippet https://gist.github.com/cbpetersen/db698def9a04ebb2abbc

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cats = new[] 
        {
            new Categories { Count = "5", ValueCode = "cat1/sc1", DisplayName = "Category1/SubCategory1" },
            new Categories { Count = "4", ValueCode = "cat1/sc2", DisplayName = "Category1/SubCategory2" },
            new Categories { Count = "5", ValueCode = "cat2/sc1", DisplayName = "Category2/Subcategory1" },
            new Categories { Count = "23", ValueCode = "cat2/sc2", DisplayName = "Category2/Subcategory2" }
        };

        var categories = cats.Select(x => x.DisplayName.Split('/')[0]).Distinct();

        var list = new List<JobCateogries>();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            var a = new JobCateogries
            {
                ValueCode = cats.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Split('/')[0] == category)
                                .Select(x => x.ValueCode.Split('/')[0]).FirstOrDefault(),
                DisplayName = category,
                SubCategories = cats.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Split('/')[0] == category)
                                    .Select(x => new JobCateogries
                                    {
                                        SubCategories = new List<JobCateogries>(), 
                                        Count = x.Count, 
                                        DisplayName = x.DisplayName.Split('/')[1], 
                                        ValueCode = x.ValueCode.Split('/')[1]
                                    }).ToList(),
            };

            a.Count = a.SubCategories.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Count)).Sum().ToString();
            list.Add(a);
        }
        list.ForEach(x => Print(x));

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    public static void Print(JobCateogries category, int indent = 0)
    {
        var prefix = string.Empty.PadLeft(indent);
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + category.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + category.ValueCode);
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + category.Count);
        category.SubCategories.ForEach(x => Print(x, indent + 4));
    }
```